# Angular's XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Kimonolabs to GET data on refresh of my Ionic app. The error I'm getting when I refresh is:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/1z3pta34?apikey=U4SNiysE89aaLXSWRJgHKDZOByqSLM0p&kimindex=1.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Here's my controller:

```
.controller('NCAAFCtrl', function ($scope, NCAAF, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading) {
  var doGet = function() {

    NCAAF.get().
      success(function (data, gameid) {
        $scope.data = data['results']['collection1'];
        $scope.gameid = data['results']['collection1'][0]['index'];
        console.log(data);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
      }).
      error(function () {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'Something went wrong',
          template: 'Try reloading in a few seconds.'
        });
        alertPopup.then(function() {
          console.log('Fix this ish');
        });
      }).
       finally(function() {
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
      });
    };
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    doGet();
  };

  doGet();
})
```

and service:

```
.service('NCAAF',function($http, $ionicLoading) {
  return {
    get: function() {
      $ionicLoading.show({
        template: 'Loading...',
        delay: 300
      })
      return $http (
      {
        method: 'GET',
        cache: true,
        url: 'https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/[goeshere]&kimindex=1',
        headers: {
              'authorization': 'Bearer [goeshere]'
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: please google that error .... issue comes up daily here and you won't have problems researching what it means

Comment: Let me clarify: I am unsure how to get JSONP back in the way I've abstracted the code

Comment: read the `$http.jsonp` docs but note that you can't send headers in jsonp requests. Does API serve jsonp?

Comment: Yes it supports jsonp. In this scenario, do I add the .jsonp filter onto my service or controller?

Comment: it's not a filter...it's a request method of `$http`. read the docs

Comment: Sorry - I'm a beginner here trying to figure out, based on the documentation, where JSONP goes in the service that I have written.

Comment: it is a `$http` method just like your `GET`

Comment: return $http.json (
      {
        method: 'GET',
        cache: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        url: 'https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/1z3pta34?apikey=[key]&kimindex=1',
        headers: {
              'authorization': 'Bearer [key]'
        }
      })?

Comment: please follow the docs, now you are mixing up all sorts of different parts of `$http`. Also told you that you can't send headers with jsonp requests. So if authorization is needed i suspect you will need to use a proxy for this

Comment: The docs are not intuitive to me at this point of my Angular skillset.